# Anonymous access to SharePoint Foundation on Windows 7 Home

Tags: sharepoint, admin, anonymous, http-status-code-401

I installed SharePoint Foundation on Windows 7 Home to use locally only.  I don't ever intend to expose this publicly, so I want to use anonymous access for everything but am unable to do so.  I keep getting "401 UNAUTHORIZED" errors when I go to the central admin site.  I have a different, ASP-based website on the same computer that anonymous access works just fine for, so I believe this is SharePoint related but don't know how.

I enabled anonymous access for all three SharePoint web sites, first using the Application Pool Identity and then a Specific User (with admin rights), but still no luck.  I set all the Application Pool Identities to first "Local System", and then to a specific user (with admin rights) and still no luck.

I've seen other posts on this issue, but nothing else works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can enable Anonymous access for the **Central Administration** site - just the non-admin sites.

Comment: It allowed me to enable it, it just didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Anonymous access didn't work for the non-admin sites either.  I was only able to get basic authentication to work (so long as I enabled Forms authentication too).